# React Native Modalize - cannot scroll FlatList inside Modalize

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-modalize

I'm using `react-native-modalize` with `flatListProps` but I can't scroll the `flatList`, I tried `panGestureEnabled={false}`, or remove the `height` style but none of them fix it, here is my code:

```
<Modalize
  ref={ref}
  children={children}
  adjustToContentHeight={true}
  onOverlayPress={closeModal}
  onClosed={onCloseCallback}
  HeaderComponent={renderHeader}
  flatListProps={
    listData?.length > 0
      ? {
          data: listData,
          renderItem: renderListItem,
          ItemSeparatorComponent: renderSeparator,
          keyExtractor: listKeyExtractor,
          contentContainerStyle: dStyles.dataList,
        }
      : undefined
  }
  modalStyle={styles.borderRadius}
/>
```

```
const dStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    dataList: {
      height: 400,
    },
  });
```

I check the `listData` and the array has 63 items but the `flatList` only render the first 9 items.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding to `flatListProps` these props:

`initialNumToRender: 10`

`maxToRenderPerBatch:10`

And add to `<Modalize` prop `disableScrollIfPossible={false}`

I'm not sure why but the `height` is also need to be removed. So this is new code:

```
<Modalize
      ref={ref}
      children={children}
      adjustToContentHeight={true}
      disableScrollIfPossible={false}
      onOverlayPress={closeModal}
      onClosed={onCloseCallback}
      HeaderComponent={renderHeader}
      flatListProps={
        listData?.length > 0
          ? {
              data: listData,
              renderItem: renderListItem,
              ItemSeparatorComponent: renderSeparator,
              keyExtractor: listKeyExtractor,
              initialNumToRender: 10,
              maxToRenderPerBatch: 10,
            }
          : undefined
      }
      modalStyle={styles.borderRadius}
    />
```

As I mentioned, I cannot limit the `FlatList` height, so if the list is long enough, `<Modalize` will be expanded full screen, that is the limitation of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is causing because of
**adjustToContentHeight={true}**
You can control it by doing this

```
adjustToContentHeight={listData?.length > 3 ? false : true}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "adjustToContentHeight" prop is used to control whether a component adjusts its height dynamically based on its content. When set to `false`, the component's height remains fixed and does not change based on the content it holds

Example
<Modalize

```
adjustToContentHeight={false}>
```

....